# What is the best way to do a nav bar search box in Django?

Tags: django, search-box

I would like to have a search box integrated into a nav bar that appears on the top of each page (hey, there is an example of what I am talking about up there at the top of this StackOverflow page).

Perhaps the nav.html may look like:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="/products"></li>
    <li><a href="/service"></li>
    <li>{{ nav_search_form.as_p }}</li>
</ul>
```

Perhaps forms.py may contain:

```
class NavSearchForm(forms.Form):
  query = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False)
```

With the DRY principle I do not want views.py to be looking for a 'query' on every page like:

```
def ProductsPage(request):
    search_form = NavSearchForm()
    if request.GET.has_key('query'):
        query = request.GET['query'].strip()
    # deal with 'Products' here...

def ServicePage(request):
    search_form = NavSearchForm()
    if request.GET.has_key('query'):
        query = request.GET['query'].strip()
    # deal with 'Service' here...
```

I have and can easily program a page that will handle the search query and show results.  How do you best extract the search terms and direct the user to that search page (return HttpResponseRedirect('/results/?query=' + query)) without stripping the request.GET on every page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just have the search form do a GET on your common search URL.

```
<form action="/search/" method="get">
...
</form>
```

Use the URL reverse lookup facility if you don't want to hardwire the URL...

```
<form action="{% url my-search-view %}" method="get">
...
</form>
```

Unless I misunderstood the question, it sounds like maybe you were thinking that forms have to get/post to the same URL that loaded the current page.

Comment: Adjust accordingly if you are using Javascript instead of a 'static' form submission.

Comment: @Daniel Yep.  In the case of a search, I prefer GET because the URL can be bookmarked, sent via email, etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

We use a [Google CSE](http://www.google.com/cse/) on one of our sites and it's about as straightforward as you can get. There are a couple of features you can turn on, but it's trivial and you get all the standard Google Goodness™.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use separate view as Joe Holloway suggests.
2. Use forms power

   ```
   def ProductsPage(request):
       search_form = NavSearchForm(request.GET)
       if search_form.is_valid():
           ....
   ```